# Using logical OR with Crystal Reports parameter

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am working on a Crystal Reports in Visual Studio 2010 and I have a variety of different parameters and prompts for the user to filter out the specific data they want. For example, I have a parameter for Account and a parameter for Product Name dynamically populated. By default, if a user selects a filter for each of these parameters (account A and product B for example) a logical AND is performed. Only rows containing account A and product B are returned.

Is there a way to make this behave as an OR or an AND (user specifies?) So I can return all rows for account A OR product B

I know that it would be easy to change my formulas to treat this as an OR but what I would really like is for the user to be able to somehow specify whether or not the parameter should be treated as an AND or an OR.

Comment: Do you see something like `{@Account} = {Table.Account} AND {@ProductName} = {Table.ProductName}` in your Record Selection Formula in the report?

Comment: The way I have been writing my formulas so far is a series of if statements checking for the parameter values:
if HasValue({?Account Name}) then
    {AlgorithmActivity.Account} = {?Account Name}
else
    True and
if HasValue({?Product Name}) and IsNull({?Product Name Manual Entry}) then
   {AlgorithmActivity.ProductName} = {?Product Name} 
else
    True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you can pass a third string parameter in, call it `{?Logic}`, which contains either "AND" or "OR", and from there you can do:

```
IF {?Logic} = "AND"
' Do your AND code here
ELSE
' Do your OR code here
```

I realize you're basically repeating the query, once using `AND` and once using `OR`, but as long as the query isn't too cumbersome, this might be the cleanest way to do it.

Comment: Thats a really good idea. I am currently fine with the way things are working but the higher ups are trying to determine whether they need that kind of flexibility when it comes to selecting data for the reports. If they wanna move forward with that I will definitely use this.